# strange ssl error on ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems

Just getting started on Ruby and I can't get past the error posted below. Here's my code:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'JSON'
require 'Pry'
require 'csv'

page = HTTParty.get('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/pet?s=0')

Pry.start(binding)
```

error in console:

> C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock':
>   SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
>   (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in`connect'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in`start'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/httparty/request.rb:118:in`
>   perform'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/HTTParty.rb:560:in
>   `perform_request'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/HTTParty.rb:486:in`
>   get'
>           from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/HTTParty.rb:598:in
>   `get'
>           from web_scraper.rb:7:in`'

I've been online and replaced GlobalSignRootCA.pem and tried rerunning but no luck. Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby and gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because the request tries to verify the ssl key you are sending/receiving.

You can avoid the error by adding

```
verify: false
```

to your call.

More details [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/docs/README.md#working-with-ssl).